# Interchange of Expectation and integral by Fubini's theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I read a condition that if we have $E[\int_0^1 |X_t|dt] < \infty$, then we may apply Fubini's theorem and we can have $E[\int_0^1 X_tdt] = \int_0^1 E[X_t]dt$.

Though I am not sure. Is it right? And please refer to a textbook where I can get this form of Fubini's theorem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The hypothesis implies integrability of $X_t(\omega)$ on the product space so the conclusion follows. Any book on measure theory is a good reference for this.

Comment: As long as $(\omega,t) \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is integrable (meaning measurable with respect to the product measure and $(\omega,t) \mapsto |X_t(\omega)|$ is integrable) then yes, Fubini applies. Durrett's book if you want a terse reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really helpful for me.